# php variables trying to concatinate one to another

Tags: php, variables, loops

I have too variables 1 called `$image_error_0` (zero with increment as it is added while in a loop.

I am using this var in a view of mine , that creates a form, I need to print that var out to the user if it isset, however as it in a loop, I need to print as recurring number,

I have tried doing the the following, `$image_error_.$i` thinking that this would work, however I just get the following error,

`[Fri Oct 28 08:34:49 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ')'`

How can I make it so that the number of on the `$image_error` var incremenets with each loop in my view?

Comment: Have you considered using an array instead?

Comment: and using the key to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only chance to do that would be something like `eval('$image_error_' . $i)`, which is a pretty bad idea. You really should consider using an array for what you want to do. Maybe something like this:

```
$images = array();
$images[0] = array('error' => null, 'src' => 'http://...');
```

If that's sort of what you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

That would be `${'image_error_'.$i}`  see http://docs.php.net/language.variables.variable
But as mentioned earlier you should consider using arrays instead.